# Mongoid fields not being persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

So I have a pretty simple mongoid class:

```
class Offer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :date, type: DateTime
  field :accepted, type: Boolean

  scope :accepted, where(accepted: true)
  scope :denied, where(accepted: false)

  belongs_to :from, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :from_offers
  belongs_to :to, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :to_offers
  belongs_to :update 
end
```

However, after creation, NONE of its fields can be updated. If I do something like offer.accepted = true and then offer.save!, there are no errors raised, but once the action is completed and you refresh the page or w/e the changes get reverted. I don't really know how to proceed. Any help?

UPDATE: shouldn't my update class have an offer_id field?

```
=> #<Update _id: 4e6933836066250375000033, _type: nil, updated_at: 2011-09-08 21:28:44 UTC, type: "offer", unread: false, topic_id: nil, post_id: nil, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4e692ad3606625123b000001'), profile_id: nil, commenter_id: BSON::ObjectId('4e692b0b606625037500002a')>
```

UPDATE2: I'm thinking this might be a bug with has_one. I've reverted to just storing the update's id in a string field instead of a has_one connection and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was also reported as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1233).

I was unable to reproduce the problem with Mongoid 2.2.0, or on the 2.2.0-stable branch (as of d6ace09c).

This code:

```
class Offer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :date, type: DateTime
  field :accepted, type: Boolean

  scope :accepted, where(accepted: true)
  scope :denied, where(accepted: false)

  belongs_to :from, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :from_offers
  belongs_to :to,   class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :to_offers
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :from_offers,  :class_name => 'Offer', :inverse_of => :from
  has_many :to_offers,    :class_name => 'Offer', :inverse_of => :to
end

User.delete_all
Offer.delete_all

user1 = User.create
user2 = User.create
user3 = User.create
puts "user1 ID = #{user1.id}"
puts "user2 ID = #{user2.id}"
puts "user3 ID = #{user3.id}"

Offer.create(
  :date     => Date.today,
  :accepted => false,
  :from     => user1,
  :to       => user2,
)

ap Offer.first.attributes
Offer.first.update_attributes :accepted => true, :to => user3
ap Offer.first.attributes
```

Produced this output, which shows that the `offer` was updated successfully:

```
user1 ID = 4e696a052b58af5dce000001
user2 ID = 4e696a052b58af5dce000002
user3 ID = 4e696a052b58af5dce000003
{
         "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('4e696a052b58af5dce000004'),
        "date" => 2011-09-08 04:00:00 UTC,
    "accepted" => false,
     "from_id" => BSON::ObjectId('4e696a052b58af5dce000001'),
       "to_id" => BSON::ObjectId('4e696a052b58af5dce000002')
}
{
         "_id" => BSON::ObjectId('4e696a052b58af5dce000004'),
        "date" => 2011-09-08 04:00:00 UTC,
    "accepted" => true,
     "from_id" => BSON::ObjectId('4e696a052b58af5dce000001'),
       "to_id" => BSON::ObjectId('4e696a052b58af5dce000003')
}
```